# How do I access a custom object field within a NSMutable Array?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a custom object like:

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


    @interface FaxRecipient : NSObject {


        NSString * contactID;
        NSString * name;
        NSString * fax;
        NSString * company;
        NSString * phone;

    }
    @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *contactID;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *name;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *fax;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *company;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *phone;

    @end
```

I have an array of NSMutableArray (remoteRecipientItems )containing FaxRecipient objects.

However I am trying to just set the value of a UITableView cell by using the name:

```
[[cell textLabel]setText:[remoteRecipientItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]]; //I want to only use the name value of FaxRecipient. Sorry for the newbie question.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
FaxRecipient *faxObject= [remoteRecipientItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//This is ur object
cell.textLabel.text=faxObject.name;//this sets the name
```

Comment: add this one line more..before returning the cell do this.. faxObject=nil;